# showing header content of application

Tags: android

String.xml

```
<string name="HomeActivityTitle">Placement Cell</string>
<string name="FeedbackActivityTitle">Feedback</string>
<string name="EclairActivityTitle">Placement Record</string>
<string name="FroyoActivityTitle">Cdc Team</string>
<string name="GingerbreadActivityTitle">News Feed</string>
<string name="HoneycombActivityTitle">Student Forum</string>
<string name="ICSActivityTitle">Assessment Test</string>
<string name="JellyBeanActivityTitle">Recruiters Info</string>

</resources>
```

placement-regi.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Placement Registration form" />
```

i need some help regarding how to display my text on header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your `string.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="STRING NAME">Text you want to display</string>
....
</resources>
```

and this to your `placement-regi.xml` textview attribute

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/STRING NAME"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Saved your string at `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

This layout `XML` applies a string to a `View`:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello" />
```

This application code retrieves a string:

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```